# Gather all records from one table and SUM a field from another table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to fetch all of the `invoices` a client has, then calculate the SUM from `payments`. Problem is, the SUM from `paid_to_date` is the same value on all returned rows.

[Here's a SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/25dc7/1).

```
SELECT `invoices`.*, 
       DATE_FORMAT(`invoices`.`due_date`, '%M %d, %Y') AS `due_date`,
       totals.`paid_to_date`
FROM   `invoices`, 
       (SELECT `payments`.`invoice_id`, 
               SUM(`payments`.`amount`) `paid_to_date`
        FROM   `payments` 
        GROUP  BY `payments`.`invoice_id`) AS totals 
WHERE  `invoices`.`client_id` = 1
ORDER  BY `invoices`.`due_date` DESC
```

Comment: I want to quietly bring up that your website asks for payment details but is not a TLS secured website. (geekbocks.com)

Comment: The payment is going through PayPal, I plan on fixing this today though. ;) +1

Comment: Also as a curiosity, I look at your website but I have no idea what part of the world you work in...... perhaps something to consider for future rewrites of the text copy `:-)`

Comment: Currently, the beautiful and sunny (and don't forget humid) state of Hawaii! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a `JOIN` instead of calling both tables in the `FROM` statement.

```
SELECT `invoices`.*, 
       DATE_FORMAT(`invoices`.`due_date`, '%M %d, %Y') AS `due_date`, 
       totals.`paid_to_date` 
FROM   `invoices`
LEFT JOIN    (SELECT `payments`.`invoice_id`, 
                  SUM(`payments`.`amount`) `paid_to_date` 
              FROM   `payments` 
              GROUP  BY `payments`.`invoice_id`) AS totals 
                  ON `invoices`.`ID` = `totals`.`invoice_id`
WHERE  `invoices`.`client_id` = 1 
ORDER  BY `invoices`.`due_date` DESC
```

Edit: Changed to `LEFT JOIN` as I did not know you wanted to see unpaid invoices

Included the SQL Fiddle to prove query functions as intended.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/50f08e/2

As stated in the comment you probably have bad primary and foreign keys.  In your SQL Fiddle I changed your payment invoice ids as they were going to invoices that did not exist.

Comment: This returns no results on SQL Fiddle and phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Most likely returns no results on SQL Fiddle due to auto increment of ID

Comment: Doesn't return a result on phpMyAdmin either. Switching to `LEFT JOIN` returns results, but `paid_to_date` is NULL on all rows.

Comment: I would question the referential integrity of your primary and foreign keys.

Comment: @kneeki Included my SQLFiddle, please view my edit to the question

Comment: Perfect! Thanks @David!